# JavaScript can’t set a variable – FancyInput example

Tags: javascript

I have the following code ([From AirBnB github](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#modules)):

```
!function(global) {
  'use strict';

  function FancyInput(options) {
    this.options = options || {};
  }

  global.FancyInput = FancyInput;
}(this);
```

When I try the execute the following code in the console, it throws a `TypeError`:

```
var x = FancyInput({"a":1})
```

The error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'options' of undefined

Why can’t it set the variable? If I call it with a `this` before, it works.

```
this.FancyInput({"a":1})
```

Comment: Use `new FancyInput({a: 1})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FancyInput` is a constructor; you have to use the `new` operator to use it to construct objects. `new` creates a new `FancyInput` object and binds it to `this` inside the constructor.

```
var x = new FancyInput({a: 1});
```

This error is caught specifically by strict mode, which sets `this` to `undefined` when calling functions without a context instead of to the global object. That’s what you’re doing by using `this.FancyInput`, by the way, and it’s not correct.

Comment: I wasn't aware of tihs property of strict mode, when debugging Chrome was specifying `this` in the constructor as the `window` object, that got me confused. BTW, thx for improving my question.